# combine a string dropdowntextfield

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have a problem. I want to combine two properties for the `DataTextField`.

I tried the following, but it's not working:

```
this.ddReturnItem.DataSource = Administration.AdministrationRent.GetAllRents();
this.ddReturnItem.DataValueField = "ID";
this.ddReturnItem.DataTextField = "Series" + ReservationWristbandProp.AccountProp.Username;
this.ddReturnItem.DataBind();
SMEEvent.Rent rent;
```

In `GetAllRents` we make an object with the properties of a wristband(object), which contains an account(object) with a username. I can get the information out of the property just fine outside of the `DataTextField`.

However, I can't make a new property to skip the other objects.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What happens when you run the code?  What exactly do you mean by "it ain't working"?

Comment: the dropdownlist aren't filled

Comment: What does `GetAllRents()` method return? Code would be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take advantage of [DataTextFormatString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.datatextformatstring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property of dropdownlist.

Below is the code for the same

```
this.ddReturnItem.DataSource = Administration.AdministrationRent.GetAllRents();
this.ddReturnItem.DataValueField = "ID";
this.ddReturnItem.DataTextField = ReservationWristbandProp.AccountProp.Username;
this.ddReturnItem.DataTextFormatString = "Series {0}";
this.ddReturnItem.DataBind();
SMEEvent.Rent rent;
```

Comment: This creates an error.  'SMEEvent.Rent' does not contain a property with the name 'ReservationWristbandProp.AccountProp.Username'.

Comment: Ahh.. You only want to use static value for all options, I think you can use                                                                               `this.ddReturnItem.DataTextField = "ID"; 
this.ddReturnItem.DataTextFormatString = "Series " +  ReservationWristbandProp.AccountProp.Username"; `